# React JS get errors in XMLHttpRequest with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m using REACT-JS framework for FRONT-END:

This is my calling action from `REDUX-REACT`

```
export function UserLogin(values) {
    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',        
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    const request = axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', headers,  values).then(function(response){
        /*() => {callback();}*/
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Error
        if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.data);

        } 
        else if (error.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
            // http.ClientRequest in node.js
            console.log(error.request);
        } 
        else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
    });
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

I´m getting answer from other `localhost:8000` for testing purposes.

I´m getting this errors:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8000/login: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

And the console log from `error.request`

Comment: This is a CORS (cross origin) issue. Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164116/cors-error-while-making-axios-get-call Additional troubleshooting in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/7kfqwi/using_reactjs_axios_how_do_you_bypass_cors_when/

Comment: The server should support CORS requests. In case you have an access to your server you should configure it to send those headers. Just google cors to read about it. And if you are using node.js and express you can take a look at [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.

Comment: No i´m using laravel, and i´m using axios sending headers to solve CORS problem @GreggB

Comment: @coockoo i´m using headers in AXIOS!

Comment: Have you added: `withCredentials: true`

Comment: @OlympikeSoft yeah, you add your headers when you send your request from frontend and you have to add CORS headers with your server response from backend as well.

Comment: @coockoo any example for that?

Comment: @OlympikeSoft here you go https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/43ba206c1cde9ace35de154a5c84fc6d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` at server's response header.

For more details, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).