# Can't send GET Request with Vue

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, vue.js, google-chrome

This is my Vue Component

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div id="app">
      {{ posts }}
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      {{status}}
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from "axios";

  export default {
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        status:null,
        posts: []
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios
          .get('http://localhost:8080/uebungen')
          .then(response =>{
                this.posts=response.data
              }
          )
    }
  }

</script>
```

I want to make a get request on my Spring Programm, I can work with my backend perfectly, i can send a get request from python or postman without any problems, but if i send one with Vue axios i got this weird error in my browser.
[image: Picture of the Error]
I am pretty new to Vue, I hope i haven't messed up with some basics.
I wont get an error in vue or in my spring programm, in vue it just won't show anything

Comment: What's console logs in debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error while making axios.get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164116/cors-error-while-making-axios-get-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cors error, your browser is blocking the response due to security concerns.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a standard that allows a
> server to relax the same-origin policy. This is used to explicitly
> allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others.

**What can be done:**

- If you are the backend dev, allow your site URL (from where you are making the request)(FE) in the response header.
- If you don't have access to the backend, you can disable CORS, using
  [browser extemnsion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) for your device.

Read more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

Comment: Thank you, the extemnsion made it work for me