# How to fetch data URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React In my below code I have two button when I click on button1 then open another URL  which is fetched in API https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d based on id1 and when I click on button then then open different URL which is fetched in API which id 2 based on id fetched.

How can we do that using React?

https://codesandbox.io/s/challenge-7-fetch-a-list-final-forked-5me46?file=/src/index.js check here in my code I am not able to do that when I click on button1 then URL not fetched in API and not open. I'm stuck on that.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import ScotchInfoBar from "./ScotchInfoBar";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54"
    );

    response.data;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Fetch data from API */}
      <div>
        <button className="fetch-button" onClick={fetchData}>
          Data1
        </button>
        <button className="fetch-button" onClick={fetchData}>
          Data2
        </button>

        <br />
      </div>

      {/* Display data from API */}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `return response.data`?

Comment: Yes yes we're coming, hold your horses, you asked your question one minute ago. `const myData = (await axios.get(...)).data`, that's it. You don't even need Axios at all : `const myData = await (await fetch( url ) ).text()` (or `.json()`)

Comment: @JeremyThille can u showed me some example

Comment: https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM can u edit and showed me i m not able to do

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the id in as an argument into your fetchData function like the following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import ScotchInfoBar from "./ScotchInfoBar";
import "./styles.css";
function App() {
  const fetchData = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://mocki.io/v1/${id}`);
    console.log(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Fetch data from API */}
      <div>
        <button
          className="fetch-button"
          onClick={() => fetchData("4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54")}
        >
          Data1
        </button>
        <button
          className="fetch-button"
          onClick={() => fetchData("4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54")}
        >
          Data2
        </button>

        <br />
      </div>

      {/* Display data from API */}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: can u edit and  showed me something https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM here bcz when i try ur code its not worked

Answer (score 0):

As per the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/challenge-7-fetch-a-list-final-forked-5me46?file=/src/index.js) link, When you click the URL, you are not getting the response, it is due to the CORS error. Refer [this for CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805776/cant-send-get-request-with-vue/66805874#66805874).
You can check this by wrapping your API call in try-catch.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://mocki.io/v1/4d51be0b-4add-4108-8c30-df4d60e8df54");
        console.log(response.data);
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

**Coming to the second question:** How you can trigger different APIs on different button clicks?

You can pass different inline functions for `onClick` of your buttons, like:

```
<button
  onClick={onClick={() => fetchData("some-id-1")}}
>
    Button 1
</button>
<button
  onClick={onClick={() => fetchData("some-id-2")}}
>
    Button 2
</button>
```

and handle these ids in `fetchData` function like:

```
const fetchData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://mocki.io/v1/${id}`);
        console.log(response.data);
    }catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

Comment: I know, you are stuck with some hiring challenge and it is urgent for you to get the answers immediately, but first refer the link shared, before asking further questions

Comment: i have resolve the issue cors error after that i run the code its showing error https://codesandbox.io/s/challenge-7-fetch-a-list-final-forked-zl0vb can u plz check and help me out.

Comment: Be specific about the error you. are getting, before asking the question, what is the error, what have you tried?